# Not execute Volley JSON onResponse function

Tags: android, json, android-studio

When I call getData.It seems that it is hard to get the result out from the onResponse. I know it cannot work in this current way. Could anyone help me to settle this problem?

**getData()**

```
private void getData(){

    //Creating a string request
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(SPINNER_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
           // Log.d("Country_name","hi");
            JSONObject j = null;
            try {
                //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                j = new JSONObject(response);

                //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                result = j.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);

                Log.v("xxxxx",result.toString());
                String mysh=result.toString().substring(1, result.toString().length()-1);


                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(mysh);
                //Calling method getCountry to get the country from the JSON Array
                getCountry(jsonArray);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //Creating a request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: what is the response, u getting from webservice. Can u add json responce?

Comment: What about the onErrorResponse()? isn't it called because of some error?

Comment: Maybe if you do a jsonRequest instead of a StringRequest, it would be easier?  Also, why is everything inside a try catch?  If the response is good, then there should be no need, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this i think it should work

```
private void getData(){

//Creating a string request
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(SPINNER_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {


        try {

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
            getCountry(jsonArray);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
},
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });


RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that, this will help.

```
private void getData() {

    String tag_string_req = "req_name";
    spotsDialog.show();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            YOUR URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());

            try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("YOUR ARRAY NAME");
                for (int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                    String result = array.getString(i).toString();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

        }
    });
    strReq.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {

        @Override
        public void retry(VolleyError arg0) throws VolleyError {
        }

        @Override
        public int getCurrentTimeout() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
            return 0;
        }
    });
     RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

//Adding request to the queue
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Happy To Help.